# How to install another desktop-environment in Linux (Gnome -> Xfce)?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, gnome, xfce, desktop-environment

I have to installed XFCE instead of Gnome in Arch. Apart `pacman -S` and `pacman -R` commands, what else should I do? Will I have to remove gnome from "recovery mode" or what? I guess it's not possible to remove while I'm using it. Or is it? And then how will I install XFCE, will I have to boot in the command-line mode and will it be only way?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably install XFCE *without* uninstalling Gnome first -- there are no package conflicts. Then log out, and select the XFCE desktop session at the GDM login screen.

As far as I know, XFCE doesn't have it's own login screen ("display manager"), so be careful when you remove Gnome that you don't also remove GDM (or that you replace it with [something else](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager)). You probably want to keep many of your Gnome apps anyway, so just removing everything in the Gnome group is a bad idea anyway.

After switching, you will probably want to clean up your dot-files so that the settings you had in Gnome don't do undesirable things in XFCE (or just to free up the space used by Gnome cruft). Creating a new user is a good way to see what a clean config looks like.

As always with Arch Linux, [read the wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce) before doing anything. :-)